# TCP three way handshake fails

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock

I have a C++ application which accepts TCP connections and then reads the traffic sent to it.  It has worked very well until I moved it to a new machine.  It seems like winsock never accepts the inbound tcp connection.  In my code it never returns from the select statement.  I can see using netstat/tcpview that the application is listening on port 14005.

I can connect to this port if I just telnet in locally.  However, when someone tries to connect in via an outside IP address the TCP 3 way handshake never finishes.  I can see the inbound SYN packet in wireshark.  It is going to the correct port, 14005.  However my system never sends the SYN-ACK back.  This is just something that winsock is suppose to handle right?   The machine does have multiple NIC cards, but I'm binding with INADDR_ANY so this shouldn't matter.  Is there some way I can dig deeper to see why this handshake never takes place?

Comment: did you check the firewall settings? Sounds like Windows Firewall in action.

Comment: sounds like a firewall problem. what are the firewall settings?

Comment: yes, I did check that.  The windows firewall is off so I'm ok there.  I don't see any other software on the machine that is a firewall either.  It's possible something is slipping through but I looked everywhere.

Comment: so I would normally see a SYN packet if there is a software firewall?  If there is a hardware firewall do those let the SYN packets through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per ways to dig deeper: nothing more than wireshark / tshark (which you already use, however if you want to play with packets, look at scapy)

what happens if you reduce headache - only use one nic and network, put the client on the same network (ie, no router or smart switch between), (last resort) disable unneeded network services.